# Case statement logic gone wrong

Tags: mysql

I have a question , as I am new to programming , I Can't figure out this simple logic. I am creating buckets under this code and for some reason the last buckets that I have created i.e 5 and 6 are not working. Everything is falling under classification 1. Need some help to categorising the data in different buckets. Can someone please tell me what can be done so that the data that is meeting condition 5 & 6 falls under it.

```
case when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) > 0 and sum([Previous Amount]) = 0 then 1 
     when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) > 0 and Sum(differenceAmount) > 0  then 2
     when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) > 0 and Sum(differenceAmount) < 0  then 3
    when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) = 0 and Sum(differenceAmount) <> 0  then 4 
    when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) > 0 and sum([Previous Amount]) = 0 and [SUBSCRIPTION ORDER TYPE LIST] = 'Acquisition' then 5  
    when Sum(SubscriptLineAmount) > 0 and sum([Previous Amount]) = 0  and [SUBSCRIPTION ORDER TYPE LIST] = 'Other' then 6 
    else 7 
end classification
```

Comment: A case statement quits when the first when test is met. In your case 1 will be met when you are hoping for 5 and 6..(because the first 2 tests are met in 1 ) You need to decide if 5 and 6 are more powerful than 1 and rearrange the case statement accordingly BTW the use of square brackets implies sqlserver rather than mysql.

Comment: yeah , sorry wasn't aware about that. I need all the conditions to be there as they all are different. What should i do ?